# Material-UI chips look different on localhost and Netlify

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, netlify

I'm not sure if this is a Netlify issue or a Material-UI issue or whether there's anything I can do about it; any suggestions on how to achieve the effect I'm seeing locally once I deploy it?

Here are screenshots of the two images:

[LocalHost Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kivcE.png)

[Netlify Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVasM.png)

Here's my code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  chip: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    zIndex: '1200',
    marginTop: '90px',
    float: 'right',
    position: 'static'

  },
  avatar: {
    color: '#fff',
  },
}));
```

...

```
          <Chip
            avatar={
              <Avatar 
                className={classes.avatar}            
              >
                Dai
              </Avatar>}
            avatarsmall
            clickable
            label={daiBalance}
            className={classes.chip}
            color="secondary"
          />
          <Chip
            avatar={<Avatar className={classes.avatar}>Eth</Avatar>}
            clickable
            avatarsmall
            label={balance}
            className={classes.chip}
            color="secondary"
          />
```

Comment: This is a reported bug. The issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16374.

Comment: amazing, thank you!